# DataGridView (partially) databound custom sort

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagrid I must fill with a mix of

- Columns dynamically created with code
- Columns dinamically created retrieving data from a query (dynamic, naturally)

DataTable table;

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    table.Load(dr);

    // Insert row number column
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn rowColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        HeaderText = "Row",
        Width = 40,
        ReadOnly = true,
        Frozen = true
    };
    dgv.Columns.Insert(0, rowColumn);

    // Insert grouping column
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn groupColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    {
        HeaderText = "Grouping",
        Width = 70,
        DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox,
        FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat,
        Frozen = true
    };
    groupColumn.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "-", "Group 1", "Group 2"});
    dgv.Columns.Insert(1, groupColumn);

    // Populate row & grouping columns
    .................

    dgv.DataSource = table;
}
```

DataGridView is filled with desired data and user can alter everything he wants.
Finally I need to sort rows according to the modified content of columns edited values (both the created ones and the databound ones): how can I do this?

Databound datagridviews cannot be sorted using Sort() nor can I use Sort method of DataTable (or DataView I could put in the middle) because I have extra data.
I'm stuck with this...

Comment: So why don't you add the columns to your table instead of the datagridview? So that when you bind the table you'll get your extra columns. And if you desperately need a dropdown column just convert the column after databinding it.

Comment: @WozzeC: thanks for your sugestion, I'm trying to refactor my code and it partially works. How can I convert a table column to a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`? Unfortunately I need that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927094/how-to-change-a-datagridview-cell-style-from-the-default-textbox-to-combobox-in/12929137#12929137 Have a look at this.

Comment: @WozzeC: I see your answer there, but that column was generated by code (as mine) and cannot be used for sorting!! Do you know a way I can "convert" a DataGridViewTextColumn (generated automatically when loaded data from DataTable) to a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn without deleting and recreating it?

Comment: There is no column created in that example? It creates a cell where it previously was a text box. You just have to do a loop and replace all cells for that column. Your column should still be databound since it was added together with your datatable. You just changed the way of altering it. However, I do not have the possibility to test this right now so I might be wrong on this.

Comment: @WozzeC: create an answer from your comment and I will accept it because you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the columns in your table instead of your datagridview. 
This will make the column databound instead of creating it "manually". 
Then to turn the column into a combobox column have a look at this SO link:
[How to change a datagridview cell style from the default textbox to combobox in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927094/how-to-change-a-datagridview-cell-style-from-the-default-textbox-to-combobox-in/12929137#12929137)