# vb.net change datagridview column type to combobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, textbox, cell

can I change textbox column in datagridview in vb.net to combobox column type at run time? I know that can be done in design time but I want to do that programatically.

Comment: My first question would be: what have you tried already?  Second question would be: why do you need to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927094/how-to-change-a-datagridview-cell-style-from-the-default-textbox-to-combobox-in/12929137#12929137

Comment: Till now I could add a combobox column and hide some columns and did it right. But is there away to change the column type instead of adding new column?

Comment: I have employee and department tables. Employee tables has a foreign key departmentId that is a primary key in department table. When I load the employees table I got all the details with the departmentId not the department name. Now I need the code that changes the departmentId column in the datagridview to a combobox column. So that I can select the department name instead of typing the departmentId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in runtime you will have to remove the column and then add a combobox column. Make sure that the Items list of your combobox contains the data value or an exception will be thrown.

```
With DataGridView1
    If .Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    i = Datagridview1.currentrow.index

    Dim gridComboBox As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    gridComboBox.Items.Add("A") 'Populate the Combobox
    gridComboBox.Items.Add("B") 'Populate the Combobox
    gridComboBox.Items.Add("C") 'Populate the Combobox
    .Item(8, i) = gridComboBox
End With
```